# How to create repeatable event php/mysql (weekly)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an event which should repeat every week at the same time.

**This is what I have right now**:

User sends `postString` to my php script looking like this:

```
weekly=true&dateFrom=2016-10-01 14:00&dateTo=2016-10-01 15:00&usrId=1
```

Then my MySQL statement with php script insert these data to MySQL DB.
This is my inserting function:

```
public function newEvent($weekly, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $usrId) {

    $sql = "insert into myTableName set weekly=?, dateFrom=?, dateTo=?, usrId=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement)
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    $statement->bind_param("ssss", $weekly, $price, $sport, $participants, $latitude, $longitude, $description, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $usrId, $title);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();
    return $returnValue;
}
```

It works fine , but my **actual goal is**:

When user sends `postString` like example above and if ***weekly is true***
I would like my event to repeat every week at the same time and I would like to be able to search the event in some future week.

**Example**: My `weekly=true&dateFrom=2016-10-01 14:00&dateTo=2016-10-01 15:00&usrId=1` is like this and if I ran this MySQL statement

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTableName WHERE dateFrom >= 2016-10-08 13:00 
        AND dateTo <= 2016-10-08 16:00 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I would like to get the data from my event which had time `dateFrom=2016-10-01 14:00&dateTo=2016-10-01 15:00` when it was created.

My question is:

**Is there any way how can I accomplish the thing I have just described?**

If you need more details just let me know. 
Thank you very much :)

Comment: use cron job ....

Comment: Why don't you use cronjobs?

Comment: I am mostly iOS developer so I use php/MySQL very marginally.

Comment: I don't understand. You're duplicating the original event each day when it is weekly? How do you keep reference to the original event? I would expect your SELECT statement to include "where weekly='true'" or something like that. Or have PHP handle it right after: if weekly do this, else...

Comment: When one user1 does this SELECT *
    FROM myTableName WHERE dateFrom >= 2016-10-08 13:00 
        AND dateTo <= 2016-10-08 16:00 LIMIT 0 , 30 I would like to show him the original event from other user2 weekly=true&dateFrom=2016-10-01 14:00&dateTo=2016-10-01 15:00&usrId=1 but user1 is looking for his date and he does not know the original time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

Add two columns: `weeklyDateFrom`, `weeklyDateTo`, which storages the minutes from Monday 0:00.

For example, for `2016-10-01 13:00` is `Sat. 13:00`, you just storage it as `7560`, because *5day+6h=126h=7560min*.  Then `2016-10-01 15:00` is `7720`.

When you want to search `10-08 12:00 ~ 16:00`, just do:

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTableName WHERE weeklyDateFrom >= 7500
    AND weeklyDateTo <= 7780 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And you will get it, with all the original event data not missing!

Hope this works! Have a good day!

Comment: Awesome Idea!! I will definitely try it

Comment: @0ndre_ thanks for your appreciation! (If you like it, you can choose it as the best answer and give it a vote up.)

Comment: I have already voted up and I will accept it when I solve my problem. :)